# How can I declare a file for inline css in typoscript?

Tags: typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I want to optimize a website for google page speed and for a 100/100 score I need to declare css inline. I know that I can declare css inline like this way:

**working example**

```
page.headerData {
  10 = TEXT
  10.wrap = <style>|</style>
  10.value (
      .example{color:#123}
  )
}
```

But I dont like this way and want to declare a file and load the content of this file instead for better maintenance like:

**pseudocode**

```
page.headerData {
  10 = TEXT
  10.wrap = <style>|</style>
  10.value < {$publicMedia}Css/inline.css
}
```

**inline.css**

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.example {
  color:#123;
}
```

**desired output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
  <style>
    * {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    .example {
      color:#123;
    }
  </style>
</head>
...
```

Is there a way to do that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t think there is a way to inline an external css file in ts.
But there are 2 workarounds.

1. Use external ts-file an include it to your default ts:
   `<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT:source="file:fileadmin/templates/ts/myinlinestyles.ts">`
   In your external ts-file you can work the normal way.
   `page.headerData {
     10 = TEXT
     10.wrap = <style>|</style>
     10.value (
         .example{color:#123}
     )
   }`
2. Use Fluid-Template.

Also you have misspelled your value declaration(= not <).
**<** means object copy. [See TypoScript syntax.](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/Syntax/TypoScriptSyntax/Index.html#syntax-object-copying)

Google say "only use for small Resources". And as you can see on the linked page is that the inline approuch have some Limitations e.g. cacheability. 
The important is that you should minimize/compress and concatenate your CSS-/JS-files. TYPO3 have a nice solution for this. Please have a look at the [TYPO3-Documentation - section setup->config](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html) and search for compressCss and concatenateCss.

Comment: Yeah I know that the second typoscript is not working, it was more a pseudocode example. but If I use your code then he will just add a link to the head, but not inline css or am I wrong? So your code is like "includeCSS" which already exists, but I want inline css inside a style-Tag. So that the content of a css file will be rendered in a style tag and not as a link to a stylesheet.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but your workarounds makes no sense for me, because your first workaround only include a external ts file, but that is definitly not what I want and your second workaround has nothing to do with the question in my opinion, because I just want to know how I can add the content of a stylesheet file into a typoscript object. Sure I will rendering the whole with fluid, but that's not the question. I have updated my question, too and hope it is clearer now.

Comment: As you can see in my answer there is **no way** to do what you want. Also [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/InlineSmallResources) say "only use for small Resources". And as you can see on the linked page is that the inline approuch have some Limitations e.g. cacheability. Please look my enhanced answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I can't handle this case only with TypoScript, but maybe it is possible with php and a user function, because with php I can load contents of a file, so I will try this. I already know all this things like html, css, js compress and concatenate and I already get a page score of 97/100, but I want a 100/100 with a good maintenance solution and yes I don't load the whole css inline, just the "above the fold" css.

Answer (score 1):

In contemporary version of TYPO3 (9.5 LTS and newer) just use

```
page {
  includeCSS {
    file = PATH_TO_FILE
    file.inline = 1
  }
}
```

The result is the embedded content of the file, enclosed in style tags.